# RecyclerView inside fragment not Clickable

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclick

Silly question probably but i cant find why my RecyclerView not responding to clicks. The RV is in a fragment, i added an interface to the adapter and im implementing it to the fragment. But while trying the click the emulator does not even does the "click" sound

This is my adapter

```
public class ArtistsRvAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ArtistsRvAdapter.ArtistViewHolder> {
private List<Artist> mArtists;
private Context mContext;

final private ItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

public ArtistsRvAdapter(Context c, ItemClickListener listener){
    mContext=c;
    mItemClickListener =listener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ArtistsRvAdapter.ArtistViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.artist_list_item;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;
    View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, viewGroup, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
    ArtistViewHolder viewHolder = new ArtistViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ArtistViewHolder artistViewHolder, int position) {
    Artist artist = this.mArtists.get(position);
    Log.d("rv adapter ", "artist img " + artist.getArtistImageUrl());
    String image = artist.getArtistImageUrl();

    Picasso.get()
            .load(image)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .into(artistViewHolder.artistImage);
        artistViewHolder.artistName.setText(artist.getArtistName());
    Log.d("rv adapter ", "artist name " + artist.getArtistName());
        artistViewHolder.artistGenre.setText(artist.getArtistGenre());
        artistViewHolder.concertDate.setText(artist.getConcertDate());
        artistViewHolder.concertLocation.setText(artist.getConcertLocation());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != mArtists ? mArtists.size() : 0);
}

public class ArtistViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    ImageView artistImage;
    TextView artistName;
    TextView artistGenre;
    TextView concertLocation;
    TextView concertDate;

    public ArtistViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
            artistImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.artist_image);
            artistName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.artist_name);
            artistGenre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.artist_genre);
            concertLocation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.concert_location);
            concertDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.concert_date);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String elementID = mArtists.get(getAdapterPosition()).getKey();
        Log.d(" adapter " , "position clicked " + getAdapterPosition());
        mItemClickListener.onItemClickListener(elementID);
    }
}

public interface ItemClickListener {
     void onItemClickListener(String itemId);
  }

public void setArtists(List<Artist> artists){
    mArtists = artists;
    Log.d("rv " , "list artists " + mArtists);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

And this is the fragment

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment implements ArtistsRvAdapter.ItemClickListener {

private ArtistsRvAdapter mAdapter;
private String LOG_TAG = BaseFragment.class.getSimpleName();
private View mRootView;
@BindView(R.id.rv)
RecyclerView recyclerView;
private Context mContext;
private AppDatabase mDb;

public BaseFragment(){}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mRootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.base_fragment, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, mRootView);
    mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);

    mDb = AppDatabase.getInstance(getActivity());

    mAdapter = new ArtistsRvAdapter(mContext, this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(),
            ((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager).getOrientation());
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);

    setupViewModel();

    return mRootView;
}

private void setupViewModel(){
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "getting artists from DB");
    DetailsViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(DetailsViewModel.class);
    viewModel.getArtists().observe(this, new Observer<List<Artist>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Artist> artists) {
            mAdapter.setArtists(artists);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onItemClickListener(String itemId) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("artistId", itemId);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

}

This is the xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Bacon.AppBarOverlay"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@mipmap/logo"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"/>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/min_margin_dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/min_margin_dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/rv_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/min_margin_dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/min_margin_dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout">
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: You can try to call setOnItemClickListener on the itemview and implement your onClick over there. However, if any of the childviews is clickable, then the event will be propagated to the child instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please add this line "itemView.setOnClickListener(this);" in "ArtistViewHolder"s constructor

```
 public ArtistViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
            artistImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.artist_image);
            artistName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.artist_name);
            artistGenre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.artist_genre);
            concertLocation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.concert_location);
            concertDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.concert_date);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `ArtistViewHolder` after `super(itemView);` add

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: is it working bro? The parameter of  setOnClickListener should be the instance of ArtistViewHolder . Because of onClick override by ArtistViewHolder . Thank you.

Comment: update my answer. Yes we have to pass the callable as an argument of `setOnClickListener`